# File watcher failed repeatedly and has been disabled

Tags: android-studio

Since an unexpected power loss a while back (my computer just went off) I'm getting this pesky warning from Android Studio at launch:

> /!\ External file changes sync may be slow
>
> File watcher failed repeatedly and has been disabled

I understand the message, but I have no idea what I should do about it. Apart from that warning I have not experienced system instability. Running on Ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you go to Help - Collect Logs and Diagnostic Data you'll get a zip file containing (among others) idea.log, which should contain the error.

Probably you'll find this: `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version` GLIBC_2.33' not found` which indicates some component is compiled against a libc version newer than what is in Ubuntu 20.04.
If this is the error you get there's not much you can do except upgrading Ubuntu to a newer version.

Comment: It looks like the issue with needing glibc 2.33 is now fixed, in Android Studio Chipmunk 2021.2.1 Patch 2, released just last week:  https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/225751091#comment29 So you can now fix this issue by just upgrading Android Studio.

Comment: The show in explorer doesn't work since I'm running in a remote docker container. How do I manually locate this zip file?

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is that `/usr/local/go` has limited/no permissions. Import will `go mod download` in `/usr/local/go/pkg/` and cannot do that. Make sure you have the correct permission rights.

One suggestion, just to confirm that this is correct or not, you can temporary `sudo chmod 0777 -R /usr/local/go/` and try to resync packages.